# How to disable a method in java @component class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using java 8 with spring boot
I have a class

```
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
class Sample{
    @Scheduled(cron = "00 00 00 * * *")
    public void print(){
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

This method is will be invoked daily at 00:00:000 AM
Now for a time beeing I want to stop invoking that method.
One way we can comment the method.
Is there any better way to do that?
Like `@Disabled` in junit.

Comment: You could comment out just the `@Scheduled` annotation.

Comment: How about wrapping the method body in an `if`, where the condition can be read from your `.properties` file? So you can turn the method on and off by changing the configuration alone. This requires a restart of the application though. Or maybe you can control the behaviour via a DB table that has a flag set to `true/false`. Then you can turn your method on and off at runtime.

Comment: @slauth Actually I don't want to modify java file.

Comment: @QBrute your answer seems to be fine. I didn't think of this. Thanks

Comment: Another possibility is to use `@ConditionalOnProperty` on the class level.

Comment: put the cron value ("00 00 00 * * *") in your config file and refer to that config value in the `@Scheduled` annotation. If you do not want to do the scheduling, you can change the configured value to "-", then Spring won't run the scheduled method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add condition on component like

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="schdularEnabled", value="true")
```

Then you can use application.yml with environment variables to toggle the shchedular

Answer (score 1):

You can  to use application.yml for feature flags in Spring Boot apps. This file usually defines the configuration of an application and simultaneously can be a perfect place for feature toggle. Based on a flag you can enable/disable the funcionality.

```
feature-flags:
    is-xyz-method-enabled :true
```

inside the method just simply do a check for this property.

```
  @Value("${is-xyz-method-enabled}")
  private boolean isEnabled;

  @Scheduled()
  public void xyz() {
    if(isEnabled) {
 
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think we can use application.properties also right?

Comment: yes can use it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree on the approaches mentioned above but there is an another alternative as well like the below,

To implement a Spring "condition" interface which overrides the matches method with a return type of boolean value (i.e., You can write your own custom logic with boolean return).

then, use the Annotation @Conditional(yourconditionclassname.class) on the @Component/@Configuration/@bean. This way, the scheduled method executes only when the condition class returns true.

Hope this helps as an alternative approach.

Comment: That won't work, the conditions only work for beans and components, not to exclude a scheduled method.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have corrected the post. Please uplift the post so that it can be useful for others. Thank You.